# Gets a bug when clicking another button during setTimeout interval

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently learning javascript and I'm trying to make a filterable gallery using buttons. I somewhat managed to code this but there is a bug and can't figure out on how to fix it. When I click any button and then click another during the duration of the setTimeout it displays both the elements for each button. (ex. clicked "First" then suddenly clicked "Second" both "First" and "Second" filtered elements shows.)

I've tried setting the setTimeout to "0" and it works. but the animation kinda messed up.

Any suggestions and help are highly appreciated. Thanks!

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".port-list");


for(var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        let category = this.getAttribute("id");
        
        if(category == "all"){
            for(let j = 0; j < nodeList.length; j++) {
                nodeList[j].classList.add("hide");
                addHide(j);
            }
            
        } else {
            for(let k = 0; k < nodeList.length; k++) {
                
                nodeList[k].classList.add("hide");
                if(nodeList[k].className == "port-list " + category + " hide"){
                   addHide(k);
                 }
            }
        }
    });
}

function addHide(i){
    setTimeout(function() {
    
        nodeList[i].classList.remove("hide");
    
    }, 400);
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.btn {
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .5s all ease-out;
}
.btn:hover {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
.active {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
.portfolio-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    
}
.port-list {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 31.33%;
    transition: .4s all ease;
    height: 10%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: .5%;

}
.hide {
    transform: scale(0);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
            <button class="btn active" id="all">All</button>
            <button class="btn" id="first">First</button>
            <button class="btn" id="second">Second</button>
            <button class="btn" id="third">Third</button>
            <ul class="portfolio-container">
                <li class="port-list first">1st</li>
                <li class="port-list third">3rd</li>
                <li class="port-list second">2nd</li>
                <li class="port-list first">1st</li>
                <li class="port-list third">3rd</li>
                <li class="port-list second">2nd</li>
                <li class="port-list third">3rd</li>
                <li class="port-list second">2nd</li>
                <li class="port-list first">1st</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please add your code within your question. You can create a runnable example (similar to Code Pen) by using the seventh icon from the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest solution would be to set a flag `var animating = false;`.

Set this to `true` when a button is clicked. Set it to `false` when your animation is complete.

If the flag is true, ignore the button click.

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".port-list");
var animating = false;

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  
    if (!animating) {
      animating = true;
      
      let category = this.getAttribute("id");

      if (category == "all") {
        for (let j = 0; j < nodeList.length; j++) {
          nodeList[j].classList.add("hide");
          addHide(j);
        }

      } else {
        for (let k = 0; k < nodeList.length; k++) {

          nodeList[k].classList.add("hide");
          if (nodeList[k].className == "port-list " + category + " hide") {
            addHide(k);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

function addHide(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {

    nodeList[i].classList.remove("hide");
    animating = false;
    
  }, 400);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s all ease-out;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.portfolio-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.port-list {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 31.33%;
  transition: .4s all ease;
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: .5%;
}

.hide {
  transform: scale(0);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="btn active" id="all">All</button>
  <button class="btn" id="first">First</button>
  <button class="btn" id="second">Second</button>
  <button class="btn" id="third">Third</button>
  <ul class="portfolio-container">
    <li class="port-list first">1st</li>
    <li class="port-list third">3rd</li>
    <li class="port-list second">2nd</li>
    <li class="port-list first">1st</li>
    <li class="port-list third">3rd</li>
    <li class="port-list second">2nd</li>
    <li class="port-list third">3rd</li>
    <li class="port-list second">2nd</li>
    <li class="port-list first">1st</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! It actually works! Thanks for the help! Also can you give comments on how I coded this? Any improvements that I can do on the code (ex. can it be shorten or etc.)